# Add Barcode font to SSRS report server side

Tags: reporting-services, fonts, ssrs-2008-r2

Trying to add the font barcode3of9 to ssrs report. It works perfect on local machine as the font is installed on it. I put the report on reporting server and installed the font as well on the reporting server and other end users are unable to see that font.

Using Reportbuilder 3.0
server 2008 r2

Comment: You might hate this as much as I do: Reboot your server. I haven't found any other way, though there has to be (and of course should be).

Comment: I have rebooted server. Still nothing.